# Email configuration from lotus notes

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, lotus-notes

I need to read email using a java application. I have Javamail samples from http://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/download/javamail-samples.zip But how do i get the email server parameters from lotus notes which is configured on my system which i should use in Javamail program?

Answer (score 1):

Javamail implements the protocols POP3, IMAP and SMTP. On a "normal" Domino- Server the only protocol that is started is SMTP and you can send mails using the fully qualified hostname of your Domino- Server.

But this will only work, if your administrator does not restrict access to SMTP.

Receiving mails will not be possible unless your Domino administrator loads and configures the tasks "POP3" and / or "IMAP".

Most admins wont do that, as these protocols are not necessary for the normal use of a domino server where the communication with the clients goes over protocol NRPC (Port 1352), a proprietary protocol by IBM.

Comment: That is sad to hear. So i wont be able to configure NRPC on javamail?

Comment: You need an ID to "speak" NRPC. So the answer is: NOW, javamail will not be the tool of choice

Comment: You can use the Notes Java API sets (notes.jar or ncso.jar) to read mail from a Domino server. This will be very different from using Javamail, but it may give you what you want. (You haven't given enough info about your requirements to know for sure.) The API version in notes.jar uses NRPC, so you will need to have Notes or Domino code installed and set up with a valid ID file. The API version in ncso.jar gives the same functionality, but uses IIOP instead of NRPC. You don't need Notes or Domino installed or an ID file, but your server administrators will have to enable IIOP.